# Spread and outright futures ranked by liquidity

Tags: futures, liquidity

Is there a platform that ranks spread and outright futures by liquidity and/or by volatility?

Comment: You might find my earlier post useful: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54054/how-to-make-a-trading-universe-of-liquid-futures-contracts/54071#54071

Comment: How do you define liquidity?